# ClassCastException on getArguments() after app killed

Tags: android, android-fragments, classcastexception, parcelable

I get a `ClassCastException` after my App got killed by Android.

- First I start my app and open some `Activity`s/`Fragment`s.
- (opened Activity/Fragments: MainActivity -> PlacesDialogFragment -> ShowPlaceActivity)
- Then I press the home button to return to the home screen. (My app is still running in the background)
- I start another app and do some stuff until my app gets killed by android.
- Now im returing to my app again, the `ShowPlaceActivity` works fine
- I press back. And the `PlacesDialogFragment` cant recover the old state. Throwing a `ClassCastException`.

Here is the `PlacesDialogFragment` Class:

```
 public class PlacesDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

            private Place[] places;
            private static final String ARG_PLACE_TAG = "Places";

            public static PlacesDialogFragment newInstance(Place[] places) {
                PlacesDialogFragment placesDialogFragment = new PlacesDialogFragment();
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putParcelableArray(ARG_PLACE_TAG, places);
                placesDialogFragment.setArguments(bundle);

                return placesDialogFragment;
            }

            @Override
            public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                if (getArguments().containsKey(ARG_PLACE_TAG)) {
                    try {
                        // here I get a ClassCastException after returning to my app
                        places = (Place[]) getArguments().getParcelableArray(ARG_PLACE_TAG);
                    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                if (places == null) {
                    this.dismiss();
                }
            }
            ...
        }
```

Here the `Place` `Parcelable`:

```
public class Place implements Marker, ClusterItem, Parcelable {
    ...
    public static final Parcelable.Creator<Place> CREATOR
                = new Parcelable.Creator<Place>() {
            public Place createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
                return new Place(in);
            }

            public Place[] newArray(int size) {
                return new Place[size];
            }
        };

        private Place(Parcel in) {
            id = in.readInt();
            name = in.readString();
            category = in.readString();
            latitude = in.readDouble();
            longitude = in.readDouble();
        }

        @Override
        public int describeContents() {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
            dest.writeInt(id);
            dest.writeString(name);
            dest.writeString(category);
            dest.writeDouble(latitude);
            dest.writeDouble(longitude);
        }
    }
```

Thanks for helping.

Edit: Here is the Log.

```
11-23 11:08:32.513 22850-22850/de.package.appname E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                             Process: de.package.appname, PID: 22850
                                                                             java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{de.package.appname/de.package.appname.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.os.Parcelable[] cannot be cast to de.package.appname.api.model.Place[]
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2449)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2509)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:172)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5694)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
                                                                                 at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:132)
                                                                                 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                              Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.os.Parcelable[] cannot be cast to de.package.appname.api.model.Place[]
                                                                                 at de.package.appname.PlacesDialogFragment.onCreate(PlacesDialogFragment.java:42)
                                                                                 at android.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:1678)
                                                                                 at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:859)
                                                                                 at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1062)
                                                                                 at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1044)
                                                                                 at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchCreate(FragmentManager.java:1854)
                                                                                 at android.app.Activity.onCreate(Activity.java:955)
                                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityDonut.onCreate(BaseFragmentActivityDonut.java:39)
                                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreate(FragmentActivity.java:278)
                                                                                 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:61)
                                                                                 at de.package.appname.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:31)
                                                                                 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5541)
                                                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2413)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2509) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:172) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308) 
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5694) 
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291) 
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107) 
                                                                                 at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:132) 
                                                                                 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: can you post the complete stacktrace ?

Comment: We need to see your logcat.

Comment: Sure guys, i edited the post.

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.os.Parcelable[] cannot be cast to de.package.appname.api.model.Place[]`

Comment: Yeah sure, but on oriantation change it works fine. Only when the app got killed it throws this exception.

Answer (score 3):

here is the answer.
You can cast Parcelable[] to Place[] directly only if the parent activity/fragment didn't got destroyed.

[Device Rotated I get a Place Array from the Bundle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8EWjh.png)

[Activity/Fragment got destroyed and recreated I get a Parcelable Array from the Bundle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QKLXa.png)

So I can't cast ParcelableArray to PlaceArray from the Bundle when the Activity and the DialogFragment is destroyed.

This works only on Rotation, like the first image showing. When the whole hierarchy is recreated, I check all items from the ParcelableArray if they have the right type, and add them to the array.

Here is my solution code:

```
Parcelable[] parcelableArray = getArguments().getParcelableArray(ARG_PLACE_TAG);
if (parcelableArray instanceof Place[]) {
    this.places = (Place[]) parcelableArray;
} else {
    int size = parcelableArray.length;
    int index = 0;
    Place[] places = new Place[size];
    for (Parcelable parcelable : parcelableArray) {
        if (parcelable instanceof Place) {
            places[index] = (Place) parcelable;
            index++;
        }
    }
    this.places = places;
}
```

Comment: Why does it works like this? Can you please explain a bit more why this is happening?